# Creating a calculator in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a touchscreen program to calculate payments being made.

[image]

The calculation I am trying to accomplish is: **Remaining = Total - Paid**.

How do I auto populate the **Remaining** field with the result to this calculation as the user types it in?

I want it to happen in real time, and when the user presses the Pay button.

```
    void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    void totalBtn_activate()
    {
        totalTxt.Select();
        totalTxt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162);
        totalBtn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        paidTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        paidBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        remainTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        remainBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void paidBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paidBtn_activate();
    }

    private void paidTxt_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paidBtn_activate();
    }

    void paidBtn_activate()
    {
        paidTxt.Select();
        paidTxt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162);
        paidBtn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        totalTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        totalBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        remainTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        remainBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void remainBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remainBtn_activate();
    }

    private void remainTxt_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        remainBtn_activate();
    }

    private void totalBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalBtn_activate();
    }

    private void totalTxt_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        totalBtn_activate();
    }

    void remainBtn_activate()
    {
        remainTxt.Select();
        remainTxt.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162);
        remainBtn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        totalTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        totalBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        paidTxt.BackColor = Color.White;
        paidBtn.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private void viewDrivers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void AppendValue(string valueToAppend)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.AppendText(valueToAppend);
        }
    }

    bool dotControl = false;
    int count = 0;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("1");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("1");
        }
    }

    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("2");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("2");
        }
    }

    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("3");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("3");
        }
    }

    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("4");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("4");
        }
    }

    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("5");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("5");
        }
    }

    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("6");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("6");
        }
    }

    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("7");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("7");
        }
    }

    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("8");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("8");
        }
    }

    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("9");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("9");
        }
    }

    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotControl && count == 0)
        {
            AppendValue("0");
            count++;
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            AppendValue("0");
        }
    }

    private void btndot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!dotControl)
        {
            AppendValue(".");
            dotControl = true;
        }
    }

    private void RemoveLast(TextBox tb)
    {
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(tb.Text[tb.Text.Length - 1])) count = 0;
            else
            {
                dotControl = false;
                count = 0;
            }
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(remainTxt);
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(totalTxt);
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(paidTxt);
        }
    }

    private void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dotControl = false;
        count = 0;

        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            remainTxt.Text = "";
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            totalTxt.Text = "";
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            paidTxt.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void btnpay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Nice UI though .

Comment: I'd suggest using an event handler for the TextChanged event for the TextBox with the current value in it, which can then do the calculation and set the remaining value in the other TextBox.

Comment: I suggest to use MVVM model, it make such things lot easier. It might be hard to start, but really worth your time.

Comment: You need to set `TextChanged` event handler for this purpose.

Comment: I agree with @SumitGupta. You should create a simple view model with the properties `Total`, `Paid` and `Remaining` where `Remaining` is just a calculated property with no setter. If you implement e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the UI will get updated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TextChanged event of the TextBoxes. Something like the following would work, however, you'd need to put in some additional error handling:

```
totalTxt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
paidTxt.TextChanged += new EventHander(TextChanged);

void TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    remainTxt.Text = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(totalTxt.Text) - int.Parse(paidTxt.Text));
}
```